# React child component not updating on parent update

Tags: reactjs

I have a tab panel with several tabs. On render the tab contents are sized correctly to fill up to the tab panel height. When I resize the browser, the parent tab panel height is updated, but the tab content won't update its height. Any idea?

```
export class MultiTabs extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.tabBarHeight = 44;
}

render() {
    return(
        <>
            <TabPanel
                height={this.props.height}
            >
                <Container title='Personnels'>
                    <Personnel
                        height={this.props.height - this.tabBarHeight}
                    />
                </Container>

                <Container title='Files'>
                    <Files
                        height={this.props.height - this.tabBarHeight}
                    />
                </Container>

                <Container title='Hello World!' scrollable={true}>
                    <Hello/>
                </Container>
            </TabPanel>
        </>
    );
}
```

I have tried using state. Here's a slightly different modification using state. innerTabHeight is changed when I resize browser, but the tab content stays the same.

```
export class MultiTabs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.tabBarHeight = 44;

        this.state = {
            innerTabHeight: props.height - this.tabBarHeight
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <>
                <TabPanel
                    height={this.props.height}
                >
                    <Container title='Personnels'>
                        <Personnel
                            height={this.state.innerTabHeight}
                        />
                    </Container>

                    <Container title='Files'>
                        <Files
                            height={this.state.innerTabHeight}
                        />
                    </Container>

                    <Container title='Hello World!' scrollable={true}>
                        <Hello/>
                    </Container>
                </TabPanel>
            </>
        );
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps.height !== this.props.height) {
            this.setState({
                innerTabHeight: this.props.height - this.tabBarHeight
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you're missing 'state'.  You need to manage state such that changes are reflected in state and that will trigger the container components to be re-rendered.  Have another look at the React docs, specifically https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response. Please see my revised question. I have tried with state, but still same problem.

Comment: Ah, height is coming in from the parent component?  You need to look at parent component state.  This is where state becomes problematic.  E.g. where to manage state.  Passing state down through several layers.  This is where there have been solutions like Redux to manage state, but the 'new' way is hooks.  Have a look at React Hooks.  You can set state in one 'layer' but retrieve serval layers down.